# Preserve &nbsp; in beautiful soup object

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, beautifulsoup, utf-8

I have my `sample.htm` file as follows:

```
<html><head>
<title>hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>&nbsp; Hello! he said. &nbsp; !</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have my python code as follows:

```
with open('sample.htm', 'r',encoding='utf8') as f:
    contents = f.read()
    soup  = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html.parser')
    
with open("sample-output.htm", "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(str(soup))
```

This reads the `sample.htm` and writes to another `sample-output.htm`

The output of the above:

```
<html><head>
<title>hello</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>  Hello! he said.   !</p>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i preserve the `&nbsp;` after writing to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read and follow basic docs: [Output formatters](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#output-formatters)

> If you give Beautiful Soup a document that contains HTML entities like
> “`&lquot;`”, they’ll be converted to Unicode characters 
> …
>  If
> you then convert the document to a string, the Unicode characters will
> be encoded as `UTF-8`. **You won’t get the HTML entities back**
>
> …
>  You can change this behavior by providing a value for the
> `formatter` argument to `prettify()`, `encode()`, or `decode()`
>
> …
>  If you pass in `formatter="html"`, Beautiful **Soup will
> convert Unicode characters to HTML entities whenever possible**:

```
soup_string = soup.prettify(formatter="html")
print( soup_string)
```

> ```
> <html>
>  <head>
>   <title>
>    hello
>   </title>
>  </head>
>  <body>
>   <p>
>    &nbsp; Hello! he said. &nbsp; !
>   </p>
>  </body>
> </html>
> ```

```
print(type(soup_string)) # for the sake of completeness
```

> ```
> <class 'str'>
> ```

Another way (no "*prettify*"):

```
print(soup.encode(formatter="html").decode())
```

> ```
> <html><head>
> <title>hello</title>
> </head>
> <body>
> <p>&nbsp; Hello! he said. &nbsp; !</p>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: With this, I see the right output but it is in string format. I would need the same output as a soup object. Is there a way to see &nbsp; as in the original file.? The only way i see is by replacing \xa0 to nbsp; Any other way possible?

Comment: @Sai I answered your question *How can i preserve the `&nbsp;` after writing to the file.* imho…

Answer (score 0):

You could always use regex:

```py
import re
import BeautifulSoup

text = '<p>&nbsp; Hello! he said. &nbsp; !</p>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(text,'html.parser')
# text_str = str(soup)
text_str = re.sub(r"\xa0","&nbsp;", str(soup))
```

I think the BeautifulSoup import may be wrong, but this example is good enough to get the point across. I know this is post-soupify, but I hope it offers a different perspective at a solution.

Comment: Hi, I just tried explaining my question in a better way. Could u have a look again?

Answer (score 0):

You could just use [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
>>> text_str.replace("\xa0", "&nbsp;")
'<p>&nbsp; Hello! he said. &nbsp; !</p>'
```

---

Where you could use this in your code?

```
with open("sample-output.htm", "w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(str(soup).replace("\xa0", "&nbsp;"))
```

Comment: Hi, I jus tried explaining my question in a better way. Could u have a look

Comment: I've updated my answer to show where my suggestion could be used. Does it work for you?

Comment: Yea, This is a simpler solution. But is there something that we can do while reading the soup and keep it as &nbsp; itself?

Comment: Did you try not using Beautiful Soup? Or do you need it?

Comment: Also, how about not using `str`?

Comment: I'll be needing beautifulsoup. Not using str as in?

Comment: I meant `file.write(soup)` but that's probably not what you want